# substitute the even couple of <>

Tags: perl, substitution

```
<a><b><c><d><e>
```

to

```
<a>b<c>d<e>
```

Any idea?

I want to use perl substitute, but it's not correct.

```sh
echo '<a><b><c><d><e>'|perl -pe's#<|>#$x+=3;$y+=4;(++$n==$x or ++$n==$y)?$&:"*":'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you, replacing alternate <*alphabet*>

```
my $str = '<a><b><c><d><e>';

$str =~ s/(<[a-z]>)<([a-z])>/$1$2/g;
```

Command line:

```
echo '<a><b><c><d><e>'|perl -pe 's/(<[a-z]>)<([a-z])>/$1$2/g'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!Before,I use while loop,have no idea.